# hddtemp with raid controller

Tags: hard-disk, raid, monitoring, smartctl, temperature

```
# hddtemp
/dev/sda: DELL PERC H740P Adp: S.M.A.R.T. not available
/dev/sdb: DELL PERC H740P Adp: S.M.A.R.T. not available


# smartctl --scan
smartctl --scan
/dev/sda -d scsi # /dev/sda, SCSI device
/dev/sdb -d scsi # /dev/sdb, SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,0 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_00], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,1 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_01], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,2 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_02], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,3 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_03], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,4 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_04], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,5 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_05], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,6 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_06], SCSI device
/dev/bus/0 -d megaraid,7 # /dev/bus/0 [megaraid_disk_07], SCSI device
```

**how can I use `hddtemp` in linux when all my disks are being a RAID controller?**

*doesn't matter which disk I get temperature of*

Comment: Is it a duplicate of https://serverfault.com/questions/73244/lsi-megaraid-get-hdd-temperature ? Do you need to use hddtemp or any tool giving you temp is OK ?

Comment: sorta, but i figured out... see beloe

Answer (score 0):

here's how to do it with **smartctl**... which I believe is what `hddtemp` is using under the hood.

```
# using the results of smartctl --scan

smartctl --all -d megaraid,2 /dev/sda | grep Temp

Temperature Warning:  Disabled or Not Supported
Current Drive Temperature:     27 C
Drive Trip Temperature:        70 C
```

From there you can get any current drive temp number that you can work with.-